# KeyError in Apache Beam while reading from pubSub,'ref_PCollection_PCollection_6'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on a usecase where I need to read from pubSub and create a streaming pipeline.
I am using colab notebook, to write and test the pipeline.
But, when I am reading from pubSub, its throwing a Keyerror.

> KeyError: 'ref_PCollection_PCollection_6'

I dont know from where this error is coming.
Can anyone help with this?

Below is my code in colab.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_runner import InteractiveRunner
import apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_beam as ib
from apache_beam.options import pipeline_options
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
import google.auth

ib.options.recording_duration = '10m'
ib.options.recording_size_limit = 1e9

options = pipeline_options.PipelineOptions()

options.view_as(pipeline_options.StandardOptions).streaming = True

with beam.Pipeline(InteractiveRunner(), options=options) as p:
  words = p|"read" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic="projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/Test")|  beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(10)) | "count" >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement() 

ib.show(words, include_window_info=True)
```

Comment: Hi @Amarjeet, Are you using only a single pipeline or 2 Pipelines ?

Comment: @DhirajSingh From code which I have pasted above, I think its single pipeline only

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.